# How do I implement autocomplete in a <mat-select> component?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I would like to combine the autocomplete feature with a multiselect mat-select chooser because the optionslist will be quite long.

I've already searched on stackoverflow for the answer and the closest to an answer was this [implement a search filter for the <mat-select> component of angular material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442794/implement-a-search-filter-for-the-mat-select-component-of-angular-material)

However the examples are about table and not mat-select.

My question is, is it possible to add the autocomplete feature to mat-select. And if not could i make an autocomplete that includes checkboxes in front of each item in the list?

Thank you

EDIT: I've found out that primefaces for angular does have a multiselect list that allows you to search for listitems. It also includes a builtin select-all button! You can find it here https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect

You can install primefaces with `npm install primeng --save`

Comment: But you do know that angular material docs contains example of suggestion box right?

Comment: you mean autocomplete box? Never heard of suggestionbox. I don't need the autocomplete/suggestion box, i need a selectbox with item search functionality. There is no example of that

Comment: but thats basicly the same .

Comment: i was talking about Multiselect select box, its not the same. autocomplete doesn't come with checkboxes for each item

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can implement an autocomplete multi-select using `MatAutocomplete` and some tricks. I'm fairly sure you can't do it with `MatSelect` since that doesn't give you control over the input element. The technique is a little odd, but it works fine. The idea is to manage selections in your controller, and set the "value" of each `mat-option` to the same thing - your selected options. You also need to trap clicks to allow users to interact with the list (rather than have it close immediately when clicked), and of course provide checkboxes inside the `mat-option` items. A few other tricks are necessary as well - [here is a quick and dirty example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sx79hu?embed=1&file=app/multiselect-autocomplete-example.html) that shows what to do.

**HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Select Users" aria-label="Select Users" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="userControl">
    <mat-hint>Enter text to find users by name</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let user of filteredUsers | async" [value]="selectedUsers">
        <div (click)="optionClicked($event, user)">
            <mat-checkbox [checked]="user.selected" (change)="toggleSelection(user)" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
                {{ user.firstname }} {{ user.lastname }}
            </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>

<br><br>

<label>Selected Users:</label>
<mat-list dense>
    <mat-list-item *ngIf="selectedUsers?.length === 0">(None)</mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let user of selectedUsers">
        {{ user.firstname }} {{ user.lastname }}
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class User {
  constructor(public firstname: string, public lastname: string, public selected?: boolean) {
    if (selected === undefined) selected = false;
  }
}

/**
 * @title Multi-select autocomplete
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'multiselect-autocomplete-example',
  templateUrl: 'multiselect-autocomplete-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['multiselect-autocomplete-example.css']
})
export class MultiselectAutocompleteExample implements OnInit {

  userControl = new FormControl();

  users = [
    new User('Misha', 'Arnold'),
    new User('Felix', 'Godines'),
    new User('Odessa', 'Thorton'),
    new User('Julianne', 'Gills'),
    new User('Virgil', 'Hommel'),
    new User('Justa', 'Betts'),
    new User('Keely', 'Millington'),
    new User('Blanca', 'Winzer'),
    new User('Alejandrina', 'Pallas'),
    new User('Rosy', 'Tippins'),
    new User('Winona', 'Kerrick'),
    new User('Reynaldo', 'Orchard'),
    new User('Shawn', 'Counce'),
    new User('Shemeka', 'Wittner'),
    new User('Sheila', 'Sak'),
    new User('Zola', 'Rodas'),
    new User('Dena', 'Heilman'),
    new User('Concepcion', 'Pickrell'),
    new User('Marylynn', 'Berthiaume'),
    new User('Howard', 'Lipton'),
    new User('Maxine', 'Amon'),
    new User('Iliana', 'Steck'),
    new User('Laverna', 'Cessna'),
    new User('Brittany', 'Rosch'),
    new User('Esteban', 'Ohlinger'),
    new User('Myron', 'Cotner'),
    new User('Geri', 'Donner'),
    new User('Minna', 'Ryckman'),
    new User('Yi', 'Grieco'),
    new User('Lloyd', 'Sneed'),
    new User('Marquis', 'Willmon'),
    new User('Lupita', 'Mattern'),
    new User('Fernande', 'Shirk'),
    new User('Eloise', 'Mccaffrey'),
    new User('Abram', 'Hatter'),
    new User('Karisa', 'Milera'),
    new User('Bailey', 'Eno'),
    new User('Juliane', 'Sinclair'),
    new User('Giselle', 'Labuda'),
    new User('Chelsie', 'Hy'),
    new User('Catina', 'Wohlers'),
    new User('Edris', 'Liberto'),
    new User('Harry', 'Dossett'),
    new User('Yasmin', 'Bohl'),
    new User('Cheyenne', 'Ostlund'),
    new User('Joannie', 'Greenley'),
    new User('Sherril', 'Colin'),
    new User('Mariann', 'Frasca'),
    new User('Sena', 'Henningsen'),
    new User('Cami', 'Ringo')
  ];

  selectedUsers: User[] = new Array<User>();

  filteredUsers: Observable<User[]>;
  lastFilter: string = '';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredUsers = this.userControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith<string | User[]>(''),
      map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : this.lastFilter),
      map(filter => this.filter(filter))
    );
  }

  filter(filter: string): User[] {
    this.lastFilter = filter;
    if (filter) {
      return this.users.filter(option => {
        return option.firstname.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) >= 0
          || option.lastname.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
      })
    } else {
      return this.users.slice();
    }
  }

  displayFn(value: User[] | string): string | undefined {
    let displayValue: string;
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      value.forEach((user, index) => {
        if (index === 0) {
          displayValue = user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname;
        } else {
          displayValue += ', ' + user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname;
        }
      });
    } else {
      displayValue = value;
    }
    return displayValue;
  }

  optionClicked(event: Event, user: User) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.toggleSelection(user);
  }

  toggleSelection(user: User) {
    user.selected = !user.selected;
    if (user.selected) {
      this.selectedUsers.push(user);
    } else {
      const i = this.selectedUsers.findIndex(value => value.firstname === user.firstname && value.lastname === user.lastname);
      this.selectedUsers.splice(i, 1);
    }

    this.userControl.setValue(this.selectedUsers);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

One way is to add a manual filter inside mat-select so it will have auto-complete functionality.
Find the example code of below given solution [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4sdpf8)

add a input controller for filter text

```
    public filterControl = new FormControl();
```

add the filter text field inside mat-select

```
     <mat-select
        [id]="fieldId"
        [formControl]="custonDropdown"
        (selectionChange)="onSelectChange($event.value)"
        (closed)="onPanelClose()"
        multiple
        panelClass="custom-mat-select">
        <input matInput 
             [formControl]="filterControl" 
             type="text" 
             name="filter-options" 
             id="filter-options" 
             placeholder="Search">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async"
             [value]="option.value" 
             [ngClass]="{'hide': !option.show}">
            {{option.name | translate}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

now add a event listener for filter text field value change

```
     this.filteredOptions = this.filterControl.valueChanges.pipe(
            startWith(''),
            map((value: string) => {
                this.optionItems
                    .forEach(option => {
                        option.show = option.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase());
                    });
                return this.optionItems;
            })
        );
```

also to make the whole list to be view in next dropdown open clear the filter text field on panel close, as mentioned in the template code `(closed)="onPanelClose()"`

```
 onPanelClose() {
    this.filterControl.setValue('');
}
```

[Demo](https://angular-4sdpf8.stackblitz.io)

Comment: nice, we can also just make a keyup listener instead of formcontrol too.

Comment: but how to fix dropdown width issue?

Comment: @IgorZinchenko can you be a little more specific.

Comment: @JEWELJACOB sry i done that issue ) that a bug with material!) than you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use PrimeNG multiselect control. Only issue with that is if you are worried about themes.

There is another option using **mat-select-autocomplet**

**How to install:**

```
npm install select-autocomplete --save
```

npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-select-autocomplete

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-autocomplete